# While variable is not equal to Q

Tags: python

I am having issues with my while loop. For some reason it isn't continuing to ask for the variable "lotNumber" when not equal to Q or q.

```
def main():
    lotNumber=""

    output=""

    todayMonth=getValidMonth("the month for Today's Date: ")

    todayDay=getValidDay("the day for Today's Date: ",todayMonth)

    todayYear=getValidYear("the year for Today's Date: ")    

    todayDate=calculateJulianDate(todayMonth, todayDay)

    lotNumber=input("Please enter the next lot number or Q to exit: ")
    if lotNumber=="Q":
        print("================ Egg Grading Report ================")
        print("\t"+"\t"+"\t"+str(todayMonth)+"/"+str(todayDay)+"/"+str(todayYear)+"\t"+"\t"+"\t")
        print(output)
    while lotNumber!="Q" or lotNumber!="q":

        lotMonth=getValidLotMonth("the month for the date lot " +lotNumber+ " was laid: ")

        lotDay=getValidLotDay("the the day for the date lot " +str(lotNumber) +" was laid: ",lotMonth)

        lotYear=getValidLotYear("the the year for the date lot " +str(lotNumber)+ " was laid: ")

        lotDate=calculateJulianLotDate(lotMonth, lotDay)

        daysOld=todayDate-lotDate

        age=daysOld

        grade=calculateGradeOfEgg(daysOld)

        age=daysOld

        output= output=output +str(lotNumber) +"\t" +lotDate +"\t" +age +"\t" +grade+"\n"

        lotNumber=gettingLotNumber(lotNumber, lotMonth, lotDay, lotYear, output)

    print("================ Egg Grading Report ================")

    print("\t"+"\t"+"\t"+str(todayMonth)+"/"+str(todayDay)+"/"+str(todayYear)+"\t"+"\t"+"\t")

    print(output)


main ()
```

Of course, there are different functions in this. I can't get this darn while loop to work for me!! Help Help Help!

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the gettingLotNumber() code, as it is re assigning lotNumber before end of loop?

Answer (score 2):

You are not asking for the lot number *inside* the loop (in the while loop suite)

```
q = 'foo'
while q != 'q' and q != 'Q':
    print(q)
    q = raw_input('q? ')
    #q = input('q? ') for Python 3x

>>> 
foo
q? bar
bar
q? baz
baz
q? q
>>>
```

---

Better yet

```
while q not in ('q','Q'):
    ....
```

Comment: Maybe `while q.lower() != 'q'`, although it throws an exception of `q = None`.

Answer (score 0):

your while loop is infinite you want the `and` operator not the `or`, and a better condition would be `while lotNumber not in ('Q', 'q'):`

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the getinput line to the last line in the while loop:

```
lotNumber=input("Please enter the next lot number or Q to exit: ")
```